# What is the Vedic ritual for Bhumi Puja of Mandir?

Tags: scripture, rituals, temple, puja

Recently the historic Bhumi Puja for Ram Mandir was conducted at Ayodhya, after at least 1000 years.

Which scripture details the exact method for doing Bhumi Puja, especially for that of a Mandir?

Is there a havan involved ? What Veda mantras need to be chanted ? Who is the Yejaman when establishing a temple ? How many Rithviks are needed ?

Comment: I had the same doubt. Very nice question. Would just like to share a bit on the architectural aspect (unrelated to the question) I had read there are supposed to be 9 dhatus put below the garbhagriha of the temple as was done in this case, which should be directly below the idol and the metal top kalash of the shikhara for Enhanced energy flow between the shikhara, idol and the metals in the earth. (Basically one of the significances of bhumi pujan for where it was performed)

Comment: In vedas temole worship not given.  It comes under agamas they have detailed information